# showing first frame of a movie with movie15

Tags: animations

I am using the movie15 package to add a swf movie to my presentation, but I do not like that when it finishes playing, it leaves a blank placeholder. Is it possible to configure it so that it shows the first frame of the movie before being played, and after it finishes playing the movie.

```
\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{Third Slide}
 \begin{figure}
  [h!] 
  \includemovie[]{300pt}{200pt}{../movies/movie.swf} 
 \end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `poster` option does this.

```
 \includemovie[poster]{300pt}{200pt}{../movies/movie.swf}
```

I haven't tried it for swf files though.